# After sorting an NSTableview table bound to NSArrayController selected row no longer matches array element

Tags: swift

I have setup Double Action in IB on the table and when I double-click on a tableview row after the table was sorted, tableview.selectedRow is now different that the index of the array it was originally loaded from.

`let trade = trades[tableView.selectedRow]` lets me see `trade.tradeNo` and other model elements but is not the object from the row I clicked on in the table (due to the sorting if I've clicked on a column header... my sorting is setup in IB not in code using sortDescriptors).

Is there a way to use tableView.selectedRow as the index to do something like:

```
let trade = arrayController.selectedObjects as! [TradeMode]
```

But this does not work.... there is no  tr.tradeNo

For the life of my I cannot find out how to get the row's data.

I have iterated through arrayController.arrangedObjects like this

`for trade in arrayController.arrangedObjects as [TradeModel]{
   ....` and I can see all the correct data..
eg `trade.tradeNo`  etc.

But I just want to use an index and go grab the row I've double-clicked on.

All the web searching I've done keeps coming up with how tos on bindings of tableview to array controller.... that is all setup and working nicely.  Here is a pic of the issue.... not the highlighted row in the table beneath sorted by date descending.  selectedRow 5 is not longer index 5 in the array 'trades' shown in the details popup screen

[TableView w/Popup detail screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vREJk.png)

[2018-10-06]: I have found a workable solution although I am not certain it is the best.  After the double action (double click) is made I am making a copy of arrayController.arrangedObjects into a new array

let tr = arrayController.arrangedObjects as! [Trade]

This array (tr) has all the trades now in the sorted order.  So when I use tr[tableView.selectedRow].tradeNo  I get the correct trade.

Again, I am not certain I am doing the best thing for my app.  I am trying to use Swift and KVO and the arrayController to do all the heavy lifting.  So, I am still questioning how to do this correctly.

Are there settings in IB for the arrayController (eg. in Bindings) for selectionIndexes and sortDescriptors and so forth that will keep my original array (trades) in synch with changes in the arrayController? Perhaps I really should not want that to happen.  I simply do not know yet.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution by temporarily creating a copy of the custom object as NSMutableArray, sorting it with the NSArrayControllers sortDescriptors and setting the original array to the sorted array as the custom object. When you're clicking the table header so that the table rows get sorted by e.g. `tradeNo`, the sortDescriptor is sent to the NSTableViewDataSource where we can fetch it using `sortDescriptorsDidChange`.

Bind your table view's `data source` to `ViewController` and create an extension for it. (The two lines regarding row selection are not directly related, but you might wonder how to do it once you've implemented the solution.)

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @objc dynamic var objects: [Object] = []
    // ...
}


extension ViewController: NSTableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, sortDescriptorsDidChange oldDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]) {

        let rowToBeSelected = IndexSet(integer: (tableView.selectedRow))

        guard let sortDescriptor = tableView.sortDescriptors.first else { return }
        let objectsAsArray = NSMutableArray(array: objects)
        objectsAsArray.sort(using: [sortDescriptor]) //: or skip the "guard let" and use "tableView.sortDescriptors".  Perhaps someone has advice on good practice here.
        objects = objectsAsArray as! [Object]

        tableView.reloadData()
        tableView.selectRowIndexes(rowToBeSelected, byExtendingSelection: false)

    }
}
```

While this solution works, it created some problems in regard to text fields that I bound to the table view (and by trial also directly to the array) for *continuous updating*. So I dared to attempt an all-IB-solution and eventually figured it out. This approach requires some different configurations, e.g. not binding the individual columns `Table Cell View`'s to the ArrayController via `Controller Key |> arrangedObjects`, `Model Key Path |> tradeNo`, but the `Table View`. This worked fine with continuous updating at first, however, once the sortDescriptors were applied via clicking the table view header in the running app, `Continuously Updates Value` also caused unexpected behavior. And by deactivating it, the behavior is equal to that of the solution above.

Maybe I'll add a little walk-through later on if there's interest, but the programmatic solution should work.

Also, fyi, I only got it to work with Swift4. From 4.2 on, the binding (IB) methods from all guides I could find are deprecated; as is apple's documentation without reference to the crucial changes.